# WCF Timeout Error

Tags: wcf

Error is:

> The request channel timed out while waiting for a reply after 00:00:59.9339962. Increase the timeout value passed to the call to Request or increase the SendTimeout value on the Binding. The time allotted to this operation may have been a portion of a longer timeout.

```
<system.serviceModel>
      <bindings>
        <basicHttpBinding>
          <binding name ="IncreaseTimeOut" sendTimeout ="00:25:00"></binding>
        </basicHttpBinding>
      </bindings>
        <behaviors>
            <serviceBehaviors>
                <behavior name="">
                    <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" httpsGetEnabled="true" />
                    <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="false" />
                </behavior>
            </serviceBehaviors>
        </behaviors>
        <services>
            <service name="WCFServices.HelloService">
                <endpoint address="" binding="basicHttpBinding" contract="WCFServices.IHelloService">
                    <identity>
                        <dns value="localhost" />
                    </identity>
                </endpoint>
                <endpoint address="mex" binding="mexHttpBinding" contract="IMetadataExchange" />
                <host>
                    <baseAddresses>
                        <add baseAddress="http://localhost:8733/Design_Time_Addresses/WCFServices/HelloService/" />
                    </baseAddresses>
                </host>
            </service>
        </services>`enter code here
    </system.serviceModel>
```

Comment: Are you really waiting around 60 seconds or are you receiving this exception message immediately after sending the request?

Answer (score 0):

you need to provide more information.
i assume sometimes in the client side you receive time out. this may cause by so many reasons. here is some example:

1- bad network connection.

2- firewall block your website.

3- WCF concurrent connection configuration or max connections limit. you can increase the connection limit in your web.config like this:

```
<system.net>
<connectionManagement>
  <add address="*" maxconnection="500" />
</connectionManagement>
```

the default value is 2. for more information you can read this: [scale up WCF service](https://codewala.net/2014/10/14/simple-steps-scale-up-wcf-drastically/)